# Error "could not update: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'" when trying to update Dynamodb using Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to run the following update in Python3.7:

```
 response = table.update_item(
            Key={
                "receipt_number": + receiptnumber,
                "update_date": + str(update_date)
            },
            UpdateExpression="set receipt_status=:new_receipt_status",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ":new_receipt_status": +receiptstatus_val
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
```

The Value of update_date is "20210322"

Running this update is giving me the error "could not update: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'"

I have tried to pass it without str() function and currently stuck without a solution. Appreciate any help.

Comment: The [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.update_item) didn't seem to mention needing an unary `+` operator for a string key here. Is there a reason you have the `+` at all?

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this. You don't need the + operand when using update_item in dynamodb

```
response = table.update_item(
            Key={
                "receipt_number": receiptnumber,
                "update_date": update_date
            },
            UpdateExpression="set receipt_status=:new_receipt_status",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ":new_receipt_status": receiptstatus_val
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
```